# Converting Perl to Java

Tags: java, perl, syntax

I have a Perl file which is actually calling some jar files and I'm trying to make it an all Java program and remove the Perl. So I came up through this lines which is:

```
$blammercommand="$javapath $javaparams -jar $blammerpath -conf $blammerconf $blammerparams -cpu $cpu -i \"".$tmpdir."blastresults/*.bls\" -db \"$infilename $blastdb\"";
(system($blammercommand)==0) or die "unable to do $blammercommand\n";
```

I've already decompressed the jar files and added the source codes to my Eclipse project and have access to the main function of the related jar file. I'm just trying to pass the arguments as inputs.

My problem is exactly here that I don't know what `"\"".$tmpdir."blastresults/*.bls\""` and `"\"$infilename $blastdb\""` mean. I know what exactly each one of this variables are but I don't know how those `\`, `/` and `*` are working and how should I convert them to Java.

Comment: The `/` is a file separator.  The `\ ` is an escape character (to escape the quote character) and the `*` is a wildcard used for UNIX globs.  Since they appear to be command line inputs, I don't see why you'd need to change them at all.

Answer (score 3):

Those are just shell escaping and shell globbing. Literally written, it would look like this:

```
${javapath} ${javaparams} -jar ${blammerpath} -conf ${blammerconf} ${blammerparams} -cpu ${cpu} -i "${tmpdir}blastresults/*.bls" -db "${infilename} ${blastdb}
```

Here, the syntax `${name}` is meant to indicated an inserted value of the variable. The `system` command in Perl runs a system command through the default system shell, usually something like bash. The quotes are used to make several space-separated strings "stick together" as one argument. The `*` is a wildcard, which is replaced by all filenames in a given directory.

Comment: The `*` is replaced by "_any number of unknown characters_" to possibly match against multiple file names... it doesn't really mean "_all files in a directory_" unless it's used by itself.  For example `foo/d*f` would mean "_any file that begins with d and ends with f in the directory foo_, whereas `foo/*` would mean "_all files in the directory foo_".